# Log4Net throwing a ton of errors in global.asax?

Tags: asp.net, log4net

I'm using log4net, in my application_start i have the following line:

```
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()
```

When i build the project i get a few hundred exceptions in System.Web.DLL. When i step into them it appears to be stemmed from Log4Net, with the message "Request is not available in this context"

The exception i'm seeing in the debugger:

```
An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll
 'Request is not available in this context'
```

Here is my log4net config:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="logs\\" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <DatePattern value="yyyyMMdd'.log.txt'" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="aiAppender" />
</root>
<appender name="aiAppender" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender.ApplicationInsightsAppender, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Any ideas as to what is causing all of these exceptions? I can ignore them and things seem fine, but it takes a few minutes just to debug the application.

**Update To Include Global.Asax**

```
 Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Function(config) config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()
           config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name:="DefaultApi",routeTemplate:="api3/{controller}/{id}", defaults:=New With {Key .id = RouteParameter.[Optional]})
                                  End Function)
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()
 End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add some, if not all, of the exceptions you are seeing. Dififcult to help you without

Comment: can u show global.asax?